Is frozen Pacific Salmon wild?
The Guardian is reporting on the change to drop the word "farmed" from Scottish farmed salmon in the protected geographical indication scheme.  It says:

An application by the industry body claimed changing the protected name wording on the front of packaging from “Scottish farmed salmon” to “Scottish salmon” made sense because wild salmon was no longer sold in supermarkets, which consumers were aware of.

Supermarkets in the UK sell frozen Pacific Salmon, for example Sainsburys.  This is not labelled as farmed and I had always assumed it was part of the approaching 1 million tonnes of wild caught pacific salmon, though from that site there is a relatively small salmon farming industry in the Pacific.
Is the frozen Pacific Salmon sold in UK supermarkets wild or farmed?
It is worth noting that the page linked above says for more details see www.youngsseafood.co.uk, but I cannot find this information there.  The only vaguely relevant page I found was the seafood policy which does not say, and google cannot find "Pacific Salmon" on that site.

The answer is going to be product specific. That specific product from Sainsbury comes from China so finding reliable information is probably not possible. If you can buy Alaskan salmon, that'll be wild.

Thanks for your comment.  Googling Alaskan salmon brings up multiple UK supermarkets (including the one linked above) with salmon specified as wild.  That answers the question "Is the Guardian/industry body wrong" which was the real question.  That would make an answer possibly?

This is a cooking site, not a political one. Fish farming is illegal in Alaska, so if you can source Alaskan salmon, it's either wild or mislabelled. Most Atlantic salmon, like Scottish salmon, is farmed. If the industry body is actually referring to Atlantic salmon, they're not incorrect. You'd need to find the trade group's actual petition/statement and not just the media paraphrasing.

It's answerable on this site, but the answerer would need to be someone who's willing to do reasearch by visiting a bunch of UK supermarkets.  Both farmed and wild pacific salmon exist.  The actual question being "Is pacific salmon in UK supermarkets farmed?"
